# Want to get Users group in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm creating a custom template to verify email. For this i have created a lambda function in node.js. I need **user groups to get role** but unable to find in events. Below is my code. I have tried to find a solution but could not get it.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

const email = event.request.userAttributes.email;

console.log(context);

console.log(event.request.userAttributes.email);

console.log(event);

const name = event.request.userAttributes.name;

const template = (name) => `<html> </html>`;
  
  
  if (event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_SignUp") {

    event.response = {
        emailSubject: "Activate: Confirm LAGO Account Email",
        emailMessage: template(name, link)
    };
  }
  console.log(event.response);
  callback(null, event);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call another method from the sdk to do so in your lambda function. Group name is not available in the event. Change your function to add this before your custom message.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()

exports.handler = async event => {
  // Params for user group list
  const params = {
    UserPoolId: userPoolId, /* required */
    Username: userName, /* required */
  }
  // Check if user is in a group and list Groups as array
  try {
    const userGroup = await cognito.adminListGroupsForUser(params).promise()
    console.log(userGroup)
  }catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err)
  }
// Handle your custom message after
...

};
```

You will need to add policy to this lambda as well

```json
[
  {
    "Action": [
      "cognito-identity:Describe*",
      "cognito-identity:Get*",
      "cognito-identity:List*",
      "cognito-idp:Describe*",
      "cognito-idp:AdminGetDevice",
      "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
      "cognito-idp:AdminList*",
      "cognito-idp:List*",
      "cognito-sync:Describe*",
      "cognito-sync:Get*",
      "cognito-sync:List*",
      "cognito-idp:AdminListGroupsForUser"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:xxxxx" //Cognito pool arn
    ]
  }
]
```